# Launch xterm to current directory through thunar

Tags: directory, xterm, thunar

I am trying to set it up so in Thunar when I use open Directory Here, xterm is the terminal emulator used.

I have tried 2 things:

`xterm -hold -e "cd '{pwd}'"`

and

`xterm -hold -e "cd %f"`

the %f coming from the help box on the page:

> %f  -  the path to the first selected file

I either need to find a way to escape the %f so it is not interpreted literally("cd \%f" did not work) or have pwd execute in the first option.

I've also tried the following none of which worked:

`xterm -hold -e "cd (pwd)"
term -hold -e "cd $(pwd)"`

Comment: What is your desktop environment?  Xfce?  If so, is it OK to set xterm as your preferred (default) terminal emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change directory *before* launching `xterm`. Something like:

```
cd "%f" && xterm -hold
```

Comment: Awesome, removing the quotes around "%f" worked. Thanks for the answer.