# Thunar option "Open terminal here" not always working

Tags: xfce, thunar

I am posting here in the hope someone invloved in xfce might see it.

The issue is the same as what is reported [here](https://forums.bunsenlabs.org/viewtopic.php?id=3775) in 2017:

> When I try the option "Open terminal here" in a folder, it only works if the whole path has no spaces or other uncommon characters.

- It is also true for any actions defined in the "Custom actions" window.
- Quoting the `%f` as `"%f"` in the "Custom actions" window doesn't work either, as posted/commented in
  [Launch xterm to current directory through thunar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340720)

Comment: In thunar 4.18.6-r0 in Alpine Linux v3.18, the "custom action" "Open terminal here" has the following in the command field: `exo-open --working-directory %f --launch TerminalEmulator`. With the package _xfce4-settings_ installed, when the directory named `test dir` (with space in between the words "test" and "dir") is right clicked and "Open terminal here" is activated from the context menu, the terminal application opens with `/home/user/test dir` as the output from `pwd`. It is likely some of the packages are outdated on your system (eg. you are using Debian stable or a similar distro).

Comment: Thanks for the report @Vilinkameni, glad that things are working now, a problem showing since 2017 has finally been fixed. I should have recorded thunar's version over 2 years ago, but just for the reference/comparison, thunar in Debian stable now is 4.18.4-1, and in Debian testing, 4.18.8-1.

Answer (score -1):

Try escaping the space/uncommon characters and pipe it to xterm. This should prevent the space from breaking up the path into multiple arguments.

```
echo %f | sed 's/ /\\ /g' | xterm
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Ashley. I normally won't reply to answers like this but seeing that you being the first time contributor here, let me point out that, A) Quoting path as "..." would be a better option normally, at least in shell. B) the command that you use "echo path | xterm" is not able to set the initial work path for xterm.